# soup.find not getting all tags in python3

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get all the <a tags in the following HTML code.
But only getting the first href.

Is this because the code is in a single line and no \n in the HTML code.

```
<ul class="listing">

         <a name="anchor201"></a> 
    </ul>


        <div class="listing3">

            <ul class="listing"><li><div class="heading">Product 1</div></li><ul class="group" style="list-style-type:none;"><li><a href="/software/1229.html">  Documentation for Product 1 Series 101, Prod Release 1.2.29  </a></li><li><a href="/software/abc104.html"> Documentation for Product 1 Series 101, Prod Release 1.0.4 </a></li><li><a href="/software/b-rel1233.html">Documentation for Product 1 Series 101, Prod Release 1.2.33</a></li><li><a href="/software/notes-1232.html">Documentation for Product 1 Series 101, Prod Release 1.2.32</a></li><li><a href="/software/6528/notes-6528.html">Documentation for Product 1 Series 101, Prod Release 1.2.28</a></li><li><a href="/software/6526/notes-1226.html">Documentation for Product 1 Series 101, Prod Release 1.2.26</a></li><li><a href="/software/configure/guide/notes-1225.html">Documentation for Product 1 Series 101, Prod Release 1.2.25</a></li><li><a href="/software/configure/guide/notes-1142.html">Documentation for Product 1 Series 101, Prod Release 1.1.42 </a></li><li><a href="/software/notes-6132.html">Documentation for Product 1 Series 101, Prod Release 1.1.32 </a></li><li><a href="/software/abc123.html">Documentation for Product 1 Series 101, Prod Release 1.0.4.7</a></li></ul></ul>

        </div>
```

Here is the python code.

```
soup_full = BeautifulSoup(filehandle, "html.parser")
soup = soup_full.find('div', class_='listing3')
links = soup.find('ul', class_='listing')
links = links.find('div', class_='heading')
if links == None:
   links = soup_full.find('ul', class_='ungroup')    
   docs = links
else:
  heading = 1
while (links != None):
  if heading == 1:
     temp = links.string
     docs = links.nextSibling
     docs = soup.find('ul', class_='group')         
  docs2 = docs.find('a')      
  print ("test2", dosc2)
  try:
     geturl = docs2.get('href')
  except:
     print ("not working")
     continue
```

Answer (score 1):

use `find_all` method to get all the `a tag`

`docs2 = docs.find_all('a')` # use find_all() to get all the  tags

and iterate it to get all the href

```
for link in docs2:
    geturl = link.get('href')
    print(geturl) # print the href attribute
```

Comment: Thanks this is going into endless loop.

Comment: Endless loop because you've made a while loop with no end condition .. `links` is never going to be None

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of getting that data:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

html = '''
<ul class="listing">

         <a name="anchor201"></a> 
    </ul>


        <div class="listing3">

            <ul class="listing"><li><div class="heading">Product 1</div></li><ul class="group" style="list-style-type:none;"><li><a href="/software/1229.html">  Documentation for Product 1 Series 101, Prod Release 1.2.29  </a></li><li><a href="/software/abc104.html"> Documentation for Product 1 Series 101, Prod Release 1.0.4 </a></li><li><a href="/software/b-rel1233.html">Documentation for Product 1 Series 101, Prod Release 1.2.33</a></li><li><a href="/software/notes-1232.html">Documentation for Product 1 Series 101, Prod Release 1.2.32</a></li><li><a href="/software/6528/notes-6528.html">Documentation for Product 1 Series 101, Prod Release 1.2.28</a></li><li><a href="/software/6526/notes-1226.html">Documentation for Product 1 Series 101, Prod Release 1.2.26</a></li><li><a href="/software/configure/guide/notes-1225.html">Documentation for Product 1 Series 101, Prod Release 1.2.25</a></li><li><a href="/software/configure/guide/notes-1142.html">Documentation for Product 1 Series 101, Prod Release 1.1.42 </a></li><li><a href="/software/notes-6132.html">Documentation for Product 1 Series 101, Prod Release 1.1.32 </a></li><li><a href="/software/abc123.html">Documentation for Product 1 Series 101, Prod Release 1.0.4.7</a></li></ul></ul>

        </div>
'''
soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
links = [(x.get_text(strip=True), x.get('href')) for x in soup.select('a')]
df = pd.DataFrame(links, columns = ['link_text', 'link_url'])
print(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
link_text   link_url
0       None
1   Documentation for Product 1 Series 101, Prod Release 1.2.29 /software/1229.html
2   Documentation for Product 1 Series 101, Prod Release 1.0.4  /software/abc104.html
3   Documentation for Product 1 Series 101, Prod Release 1.2.33 /software/b-rel1233.html
4   Documentation for Product 1 Series 101, Prod Release 1.2.32 /software/notes-1232.html
5   Documentation for Product 1 Series 101, Prod Release 1.2.28 /software/6528/notes-6528.html
6   Documentation for Product 1 Series 101, Prod Release 1.2.26 /software/6526/notes-1226.html
7   Documentation for Product 1 Series 101, Prod Release 1.2.25 /software/configure/guide/notes-1225.html
8   Documentation for Product 1 Series 101, Prod Release 1.1.42 /software/configure/guide/notes-1142.html
9   Documentation for Product 1 Series 101, Prod Release 1.1.32 /software/notes-6132.html
10  Documentation for Product 1 Series 101, Prod Release 1.0.4.7    /software/abc123.html
```

See BeautifulSoup documentation [here](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), and Pandas documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html). Also, if using a Colab notebook, don't forget to upgrade your packages:
`!pip install -U bs4`
&
`!pip install -U soupsieve`